# Why my transition dont work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My problem is that i want to put some transition duration in the changes that make one button. This is my code:

```
ingenieriaInd.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  
  ingenieriaInd.style.transition = 'all 500ms ease-in-out';
  ingenieriaInd.style.width = '90vw';
  ingenieriaInd.style.height = '80vh';
  ingenieriaInd.style.position = 'absolute';
  ingenieriaInd.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
  ingenieriaInd.style.top = '5vh';
  ingenieriaInd.style.left = '-15vw';

})
```

All the changes are working, but the transition not.

I want to make that the changes that i want have smooth.

Comment: Please  edit the question and create a code snippet with enough CSS and HTML for readers to recreate the problem, thanks. Meta: [I've been asked to create a "Stack Snippet". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5217142)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set starting positions for your element:

## only css

```
#ingenieriaInd {
    width:  0;
    height:  0;
    position:  absolute;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    top:  0;
    left:  0;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}


#ingenieriaInd:active {
    width:  90vw;
    height:  80vh;
    position:  absolute;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    top:  5vh;
    left:  -15vw;
}
```

## css and js

### css

```
#ingenieriaInd {
    width:  0;
    height:  0;
    position:  absolute;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    top:  0;
    left:  0;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

### js

```
ingenieriaInd = document.getElementById("ingenieriaInd")

ingenieriaInd.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    ingenieriaInd.style.width = '90vw';
    ingenieriaInd.style.height = '80vh';
    ingenieriaInd.style.position = 'absolute';
    ingenieriaInd.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
    ingenieriaInd.style.top = '5vh';
    ingenieriaInd.style.left = '-15vw';

})
```